# Iteration over 2D array performance in Rust vs C

Tags: c, arrays, performance, rust

I am new to Rust and I have been messing around with it lately. I was curious about the performance of accessing an array with indexes in Rust compared to C.

I made these two programs:

```
fn main() {

    let mut arr: [[i32; 1000]; 1000] = [[0; 1000]; 1000];

    for t in 0..1000 {
        for i in 0..1000 {
            for j in 0..1000 {
                arr[i][j] = (i * j) as i32;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in C:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARRSIZE 1000

int main() {

    int ** arr = malloc(sizeof(int*) * ARRSIZE);
    int i, j, t;

    for (i = 0; i < ARRSIZE; ++i) {
        arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * ARRSIZE);
        memset((void*) arr[i], 0, sizeof(int) * ARRSIZE);
    }

    for (t = 0; t < ARRSIZE; ++t) {
        for (i = 0; i < ARRSIZE; ++i) {
            for (j = 0; j < ARRSIZE; ++j) {
                arr[i][j] = i * j;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < ARRSIZE; ++i) {
        free(arr[i]);
    }

    free(arr);

}
```

The idea is to create a 1000x1000 2D array, and iterate over each element 1000 times doing a simple arithmetic operation in each iteration.

The performance gap between the two is big (C version takes almost 3 seconds, Rust version takes 45 seconds). Is this normal, or am I doing something wrong in the Rust version?

Edit: I tried with bounds checking disabled and got the same results.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens in Rust if you reverse the loop controls for `i` and `j` without changing the expression inside the loop?  Does it make a difference to the performance of Rust?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include how you are compiling each program. Rust and C both have optimized and non optimized builds that drastically affect times. Also, you use heap-allocation in C but not in Rust.

Comment: Never used Rust; how is the expression `0..1000` handled? If it's not optimized away, and actually builds some kind of range object every iteration (and sub iteration), that might be an issue.

Comment: If I turn on `rustc`'s optimizations to level 3 (with `-C opt-level=3`), it finishes execution instantaneously. What optimizations have you enabled in your profilings? Additionally, you're code is not the same between the two. In the Rust version, you use an array on the stack. In the C version, you use the heap. That's probably in Rust's favor, but I wanted to note you're not exactly comparing apples to apples.

Comment: The C version makes 1001 separate allocations (IDK whether Rust does this or not). Note that it is possible to write a C version that uses a single allocation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because insufficient information is provided. Questions on the performance of programs should include the command used to compile said programs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, I'm going to assume you've compiled *without* optimisations, because I *cannot* reproduce the times you're describing without compiling in debug mode, which specifically *does not* optimise aggressively.  In this case, the difference is not so surprising given that Rust is doing more work *and* it's known to generate suboptimal code in debug mode.

Secondly, the two programs aren't equivalent.  The C code is allocating 1001 heap arrays, the Rust code isn't allocating *any*.  As a result, as soon as you *do* switch optimisation on, the Rust code runs *faster* than the C code.

So now we need to modify the C program to *not* allocate.  Given this:

```
#define ARRSIZE 1000

int main() {
    int arr[ARRSIZE][ARRSIZE] = { { 0 } };
    int i, j, t;

    for (t = 0; t < ARRSIZE; ++t) {
        for (i = 0; i < ARRSIZE; ++i) {
            for (j = 0; j < ARRSIZE; ++j) {
                arr[i][j] = i * j;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The results I get compiling with `gcc -O` (with GCC 4.8.4) and `rustc -O` (with Rust 1.7.0) are:

```
$ time ./c-2; time ./rs-1

real    0m0.335s
user    0m0.328s
sys 0m0.000s

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Which are so short as to be meaningless.  *But it gets worse*.  The reason the Rust program is so fast is that the program is so simple, LLVM *completely removes it*.  The program has no visible side-effects, so it just compiles to an empty binary that immediately exits.

There is *nothing* meaningful that can be gleaned from this benchmark, save that Rust produces slow debug executables (which is already reasonably well known).

Comment: What happens if you wrap the current programs in timers and print all the values out outside the timers so rust can't remove all the operations?

Comment: @MillieSmith: Then you're profiling printing values to the terminal, because that's going to be the most expensive part of the program (by far). And it's not a very meaningful comparison. And it's not just the Rust compiler that will optimize the program away; the C compiler likely will too with any meaningful optimizations turned on.

Comment: FYI, `-O` for `rustc` is closer in equivalence to `-O2` for `gcc`. The man page for `rustc` says `-O` is "Equivalent to `-C opt-level=2`."

Comment: @Cornstalks No you stop the timer before the print operations. And you use the timer APIs in both languages. I.e. stop using the "time" linux command.

Comment: @MillieSmith: Then you're likely to just be measuring the performance of the timer APIs. Profiling the performance of iteration itself is really hard because it's so dang fast and cheap that it just gets buried by everything else.

Comment: @Cornstalks, if the timer wants to take 45 seconds to start itself and stop itself in release mode while optimization is turned on, something is very wrong with that timer API. The OP benchmark used debug which massively increased the time, and this answer's benchmark optimized the entire program away, which, well, pretty well made the whole thing useless. Might as well find a middle ground. If what I'm suggesting takes more than a few seconds in Rust, there's still quite a difference in the languages.

Comment: @MillieSmith: And what I'm saying is that the middle ground is useless information that doesn't tell you anything meaningful (and even if it did, it's hard to find the real middle ground because there are lots of traps that are easy to fall into). The languages are different, certainly, but with optimizations turned on in this situation, they should be (and indeed are) the same.

Comment: @Cornstalks, you can't tell with either of these benchmarks whether the languages perform the same. Timer APIs are fast. It takes well under a second to start and stop one. You're hand-waving away any improvement of these benchmarks, of which there is plenty to be done. My suggestions *do* produce valuable results.

Comment: @MillieSmith: I can tell if the languages will perform the same, because it's not magic how they and static analyzers work. The languages and the compilers aren't an unknowable black box. The only major difference between the two (once the C version is corrected to use stack-based arrays) is that Rust does bounds checking, but that is trivially optimized away by the static analyzer (as is the whole program). And timer APIs may not be that fast. At best they're a single instruction to the CPU clock. At worst they're a full function call into a library or the kernel.

Answer (score 14):

*In addition to [the answer of DK.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35882837/2408867)*

To test this in a (more or less) meaningful way (and for others to play with), I modified the programs like so:

**Rust**:

```
#![feature(test)]
extern crate test;

fn main() {
    let mut arr: [[i32; 1000]; 1000] = [[0; 1000]; 1000];

    for _ in 0..1000 {
        for i in 0..1000 {
            for j in 0..1000 {
                arr[i][j] = (i * j) as i32;
            }
        }
    }
    test::black_box(arr);
}
```

**C** (uses stack, code mostly by DK.):

```
#define ARRSIZE 1000

int main() {
    int arr[ARRSIZE][ARRSIZE] = { { 0 } };
    int i, j, t;

    for (t = 0; t < ARRSIZE; ++t) {
        for (i = 0; i < ARRSIZE; ++i) {
            for (j = 0; j < ARRSIZE; ++j) {
                arr[i][j] = i * j;
            }
        }
    }
    asm ("" : : "r" (arr));
}
```

The `black_box` and `asm(...)` are used to prevent the optimizer from removing all the code. However, I used `clang` instead of `gcc` to make this work. So in comparison:

```
$ rustc -O test.rs      |      $ clang -O2 test.c 
$ time ./test           |      $ time ./a.out 
                        |    
real    0m0.537s        |      real    0m0.546s
user    0m0.532s        |      user    0m0.544s
sys     0m0.004s        |      sys     0m0.004s
```

The execution time between single executions of the same program varies more than these two programs differ in runtime.

What I want to say (and what DK. already said): the difference should be insignificant. Both should be doing exactly the same work; only that Rust also does bound checks. But those are probably removed by the LLVM optimizer in this case. Just remember to build in release mode ;)

Comment: Excellent answer and comparison.

Comment: Add a `"memory"` clobber to your asm statement to tell the compiler that it can access memory other than it's inputs/outputs, so memory contents need to reflect the C source.  See [this godbolt link](http://goo.gl/8soc6v) for a working version, using `asm ("" : : "g" (arr) : "memory");` to defeat the optimizer.  Note that initializing the array to zero and then storing to it is a waste of a memset.  gcc and clang unfortunately don't optimize away the zeroing before the loop.  Also note that with `-ftree-vectorize`, gcc and clang will auto-vectorize with SSE / AVX.